# Getting percentage by group SELECT queries to work in PHP SQL line

Tags: mysql

I finally got this code to work *within* MySQL as a single Query, but not the 2 SELECT Queries together in one $sql line of PHP code:

```
SELECT count(*) from mytable into @AgentCount;

SELECT area
     , COUNT( area )  AS thecount
     , ROUND (( COUNT( * ) / ( @AgentCount) * 100 ), 1 ) AS percentage
 FROM mytable
GROUP BY area
ORDER BY thecount DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Also still can't figure out how to use the % sign in ROUND so that the percentages come out like 53.3% (etc.).  I'm closer than when I started, but still no cigar.

I am likely missing some simple things here but the mind is frozen.

Thanks for any defrosting assistance.

-stucko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use concat function to add % sign and use cross join.

```
SELECT area
     , COUNT( area )  AS thecount
     , concat(ROUND((COUNT(*) / AgentCount * 100 ), 1), '%') AS percentage
 FROM mytable
  cross join 
      (SELECT count(*) AgentCount from mytable) t
GROUP BY area
ORDER BY thecount DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: That worked, splash58 - Thank You!   You folks are really fast and helpful here on Stack Overflow.  Muchly appreciated.   Now to figure out how to reverse the order of the PHP output to display % AREA -stucko

Comment: Just figured it out. -stucko

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT area
     , COUNT( area )  AS thecount
     , concat(ROUND (( COUNT( * ) / ( total_count) * 100 ), 1 ),"%") AS percentage
 FROM mytable,(SELECT count(*) as total_count from mytable)temp
GROUP BY area
ORDER BY thecount DESC LIMIT 50;
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution too, seahawk! -stucko